# Slick2d increase screenresolution without increasing field of view

Tags: java, slick2d

So I've implemented a scrolling camera to my slick2d game which works fine for me.
But if I change the resolution of my game, e.g. from 800x600 to 1280x960 the field of view of the player increases extremly.

This is my camera class:
http://pastebin.java-gaming.org/8a70696904d1d

Is there a way to increase screen resolution without increasing the field of view for the player?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not a 3D expert but I think that the field of view (fov) follows the size of the screen, basically, when we resize our window we have the impression that the `z axis` was also incremented to be closer to The camera, so if you want to modify the field of view, you have to alter the `z axis` (depth) so that it changes according to the( increment / decrement) of the window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this is 2D. I'm using slick2d, a lwjgl2 wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change all gc.getWidth & gc.Height in my cameraclass to a fixed value e.g. 800x600 it works.

Thanks for the help. It doesn't look really good tho, but thats another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ScalableGame Class. As long as you are using the Slick graphics and images to render the map, it should scale everything according to the resolution.

A demo on how to use it:

```
import org.newdawn.slick.ScalableGame;
...
ScalableGame s=new ScalableGame(new GAME CLASS HERE, WIDTH, HEIGHT,false);

    appgc = new AppGameContainer(s);
    appgc.setDisplayMode(705, 720, false);
    appgc.start();
```

This will scale everything including the player, menus and such.
To understand how to use it read the javadoc here: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/ScalableGame.html

Comment: This does not really help me since this is scaling the window size and not the fov.